# Is there a way to log network traffic on an Android device without rooting it?

Tags: networking

I would like to know if its possible to log network traffic on an android device and to see what app is causing each bit of traffic without rooting the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surely working, but hard to achieve solution would be to set up an access-point where you log all the traffic and connect your phone to it.

Comment: This is easy to achieve with a desktop that has a "host-mode" or "AP-mode" wireless device.  For example, Mac OS X devices with AirPort can be put into access point mode, by enabling Internet Sharing.  From there, you'd use something like WireShark to trace all the traffic coming from your Android device through the Mac.  Windows and/or Linux hosts would work the same way, as long as your wifi adapter supports AP mode.

Answer (score 0):

At lest some devices seem to have a setuid root copy of tcpdump installed